# Could not cast value of type '__NSArray0' (0x107c64780) to 'NSDictionary' (0x107c65d60)

Tags: ios, swift

My app gets data from JSON and parses it into a table view. I've implemented the scrollViewDidScroll method, and it does indeed work, but as soon as the number of table view cells reaches 41, the app crashes with the error described in the title of this post.

Why is this and how do I go about fixing it ?

Here is my code:

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + view.frame.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.8) {
        populateEditorials()
    }
}

func populateEditorials() {
    if populatingEditorials {
        return
    }

    populatingEditorials = true


    Alamofire.request(GWNetworking.Router.Editorials(self.currentPage)).responseJSON() { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
           /*
        if response.result.error == nil {
            */

            /* Creating objects for every single editorial is long running work, so we put that work on a background queue, to keep the app very responsive. */
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {


                // Making an array of all the node IDs from the JSON file
                var nodeIDArray : [Int]
                /* var nodeCounter : Int = 0 */


                for node in JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {


                    var nodeIDValue = node.0
                    var lastItem : Int = 0

                    self.nodeIDArray.addObject(nodeIDValue)

                    if var editorialElement : EditorialElement = EditorialElement(title: "init", nodeID: 0, timeStamp: 0, imageURL: "init", author: "init", issueNumber: "init", volumeNumber: "init", articleContent: "init") {

                editorialElement.title = node.1["title"] as! String
                editorialElement.nodeID = Int(nodeIDValue)
                let timeStampString = node.1["revision_timestamp"] as! String
                editorialElement.timeStamp = Int(timeStampString)!
                editorialElement.imageURL = String(node.1["image_url"])
                editorialElement.author = String(node.1["author"])
                editorialElement.issueNumber = String(node.1["issue_int"])
                editorialElement.volumeNumber = String(node.1["volume_int"])
                editorialElement.articleContent = String(node.1["html_content"])

                lastItem = self.editorialObjects.count

                self.editorialObjects.addObject(editorialElement)

                /* Sorting the elements in order of newest to oldest (as the array index increases] */
                self.editorialObjects.sort({ $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp })

                let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.editorialObjects.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.editorialsTableView.reloadData()

                        }


               /*

                        nodeIDArray[nodeCounter] = jsonValue{nodeCounter}.string
                        let editorialInfos : EditorialElement = ((jsonValue as! NSDictionary].1["\(nodeIDArray[nodeCounter]]"] as! [NSDictionary]].map { EditorialElement(title: $0["title"] as! String, nodeID: $0["nid"] as! Int, timeStamp: $0["revision_timestamp"] as! Int, imageURL: $0["image_url"] as! String, author: $0["author"], issueNumber: $0["issue_int"] as! Int, volumeNumber: $0["volume_int"] as! Int, articleContent: $0["html_content"] as! String] // I am going to try to break this line down to simplify it and fix the build errors
*/


}

                print(self.editorialObjects.count)


            }


            /* Sorting the elements in order of newest to oldest (as the array index increases] */
            self.editorialObjects.sort({ $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp })


               let lastItem = self.editorialObjects.count

                let indexPaths = (lastItem..<self.editorialObjects.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: $0) }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   self.editorialsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) // Animation implemented for testing, to be removed for version 1.0
                }

                self.currentPage++
            } */
        }

        self.populatingEditorials = false

    }

}
}
```

And here is the code for my cell:

```
import UIKit

class EditorialsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var editorialHeadlineLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var editorialAuthorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var editorialPublishDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var editorialVolumeAndIssueLabel: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


/* We are adding the labels as subviews of the cell so we can access them directly as properties */
func addSubviews(view: UIView) {
    addSubview(editorialHeadlineLabel)
    addSubview(editorialAuthorLabel)
    addSubview(editorialPublishDateLabel)
    addSubview(editorialVolumeAndIssueLabel)
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    /* Configure the view for the selected state */
}
}
```

Comment: It is crashing because when you are calling for the page data after sequence 41 your JSON object is getting value in array format instead of dictionary format and as you are trying to put that value in for loop, there is a crash...

Comment: why 41 though ? Can you think of any way to fix this ?

Comment: Its 41 because you don't have any more data on the server after that. Okay do one thing. Just wrap your `for` loop inside the `if` condition as below:

`if( [JSON isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ){`
//Your code 
`}`